# Android Studio - how to drag and drop ImageView in an accurate position

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

so I made an app that draws `bitmap` into `canvas` as a template, and I want the user to be able add images from gallery then scale, position and rotate. currently stuck in positioning the `imageView` properly, when I drag and drop in different position the `imageView` gets little off the position I placed in.

here is the `xml` of my project to demonstorate the layout structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".search.CreateActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="283dp">

<!-- reault_layout contains layout and imageView:
layout for canvas the contains bitmap
layout for the image added by the user -->

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_layout"
            android:layout_width="512dp"
            android:layout_height="512dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/canvas_layout"
                android:layout_width="512dp"
                android:layout_height="512dp">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_promo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:srcCompat="..."/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

<!-- this button to add the image -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!-- this button saves whatever in the result layout as image in internal storage-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

another issue is, the `imageView` can not be placed at the far right when I scroll, it's only placed within the visible area of the screen before scrolling.

I set the canvas layout width and height to 512dp because its the actual drawable is 512dpx512dp and if I set it to match_parent it might get smaller and harder to place small images in certain areas inside of the template.

For the template to be drawn I placed these two lines inside `onCreate();`

```
create_canvas = new CreateCanvas(this);
nCanvas_layout.addView(create_canvas);
```

I did not use `setContentView();` to not draw the template on the entire layout, so this will draw inside the `canvas_layout`

here is the `CreateCanvas` class that draws the template:

```
public class CreateCanvas extends View {

    Drawable temp_drawable
    Bitmap temp_bitmap

    public CreateCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        // DRAWABLE OF THE TEMPLATE
        temp_drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_template_master);

    }
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
     //drawableToBitmap() IS A CUSTOM METHOD TO CONVERT THE DRAWABLE TEMPLATE TO BITMAP
    // RETURNS BITMAP
        temp_bitmap = drawableToBitmap(temp_drawable);

   // DRAWS THE TEMPLATE INTO CANVAS
        canvas.drawBitmap(temp_bitmap, left, top, null);
    }

// THE CUSTOM METHOD TO CONVERT DRAWABLE TO BITMAP
public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),  drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        bitmap.setHeight(getWidth());
        bitmap.setWidth(getWidth());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

the above class helps in drawing the template into `canvas_layout`, below `canvas_layout` there's an`imageView` where the user can upload image from internal storage.

I have added these `implements` to get user touch events
`implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnDragListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`

then got these `@overrides` methods:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // the imageView that host the image added by user: iv_promo
               if (view.getId() == R.id.iv_promo)
               {
                   nGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                   return true;
               }

               return true;
           }

@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {return false;}

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {return false;}

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {return false;}

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        View.DragShadowBuilder builder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(nIv_promo);
        nIv_promo.startDragAndDrop(null, builder, null, 0);
        builder.getView().setOnDragListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {return false;}

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
 
   // I was trying thses outside if-statment to check if its working, but did not work
        //nIv_promo.setX(dragEvent.getX()-(nIv_promo.getWidth()/2f));
        //nIv_promo.setY(dragEvent.getY()-(nIv_promo.getHeight()/2f));

        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED)
        {
            // . . .
        }
        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED)
        {
           // . . . 
        }
        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION)
        {

            //nIv_promo.setX(dragEvent.getX());
            //nIv_promo.setY(dragEvent.getY());
        }
        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED)
        {
           // . . .
        }
        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP)
        {
          // . . .
        }
        if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED)
        {
                nIv_promo.setX(dragEvent.getX()-(nIv_promo.getWidth()/2f));
                nIv_promo.setY(dragEvent.getY()-(nIv_promo.getHeight()/2f));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I did not like the DragShadowBuilder(), I wanted to drag the the actual imageView
and drop on different position on the screen. but Im too consumed by the placing the imageView accurately. if possible please help me with that too